# conf "language" in org-babel

Tags: org-babel

```org
#+NAME: certfile
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(cond
 ((eq system-type 'gnu/linux) "/etc/ssl/cert.pem")
 ((eq system-type 'darwin) "~/Mail/certificates/root-certificates.pem"))
#+end_src

#+begin_src conf :tangle .mbsyncrc :noweb yes
User user@domain.org
CertificateFile <<certfile()>>
#+end_src
```

I don't see `conf` language being listed at https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/index.html

Is it functioning example or just pseudo-code org-babel snippet?
How to install it?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I used `org-babel-execute` instead of `org-babel-tangle`.

Also, `conf-mode` package is nice to have installed for such blocks.